# Laravel 4 User Authentication with Twitter/Facebook

Tags: facebook, authentication, twitter, laravel, laravel-4

What are the best packages for Laravel 4  to use for user authentication with Twitter or Facebook. Are there some good tutorials or guides.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe https://packagist.org/packages/hybridauth/hybridauth is the package you are looking for. For tutorials on how to use it, take a look inside their examples folder on their github repo.

Comment: I am just viewing that package with tutorial on this site. http://www.mrcasual.com/on/coding/laravel4-package-management-with-composer/